# Difference between if with or statement and elif in BASH

Tags: bash, performance, shell

I'm just curious about the difference between the following:

```
if [[ "${foo}" == 'bar' || "${foo}" == 'bar1' ]]; then
    echo "Action"
fi
```

and:

```
if [ "${foo}" == 'bar' ]; then
    echo "Action"
elif [ "${foo}" == 'bar1' ]; then
    echo "Same action as above"
fi
```

Are there any differences? Speed? Preferability for code readability? ..etc?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a better way of doing the same thing and if so what is it and how is it better?

Comment: See also: case/esac in bash.

Comment: The first way doesn't require you to duplicate your action, so is probably preferable for [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) if nothing else

Comment: That makes sense Eric!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more direct (and still POSIX-compliant) version of your first statement is

```
if [ "${foo}" = 'bar' ] || [ "${foo}" = 'bar1' ]; then
    echo "Action"
fi
```

The second one is just unnecessarily verbose.

There is virtually no difference between the two in `bash`, as `[` is a built-in command.

Comment: So, another question out of curiosity.. Up until how many arguments can one put in there until it's best to use elif or even switch? I keep on hearing that a person should use switch (case) if there are more than 5 arguments..

Comment: You've left a double bracket in there.

Comment: I'd only use `case` or `elif` if the action to be taken is different, not simply to break up a long disjunctive condition. If there are lots of similar conditions, I'd look for a way to generalize the test. Here, for instance, you could use `if [[ $foo =~ bar1? ]]; then` instead of two separate tests.

Comment: Well the idea was something like `if [[ $variable == 'jdk6-maven' || $variable == 'jdk7-maven' || $variable == 'jdk8-maven'  ]]; then`

Comment: `[[ $variable == jdk[678]-maven ]]`

Comment: Oh! That's awesome, didn't know one could do that!